Why was Monty so afraid of being raped?
In the movie "25th Hour", Monty (played by Edward Norton) is constantly worried about being gang raped in federal prison. Particularly because he's considered "handsome".
We see him and his friends constantly talk about this and it is also being implied by other characters we meet throughout the film.
Is it an irrational fear? Was/is this actually a real thing in US/New York prisons for inmates/felons? Why wasn't he as worried about his health for instance, or actually surviving those 7 years of incarceration?

Prison rape in the US is incredibly common. In some facilities, levels as high as 20% of inmates reported having suffered unwanted sexual advances and 7% had been forcibly sodomised by another prisoner; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prison_rape_in_the_United_States. More men are raped in US prisons than women are raped outside.


Is it an irrational fear?

No; see below.

Was/is this actually a real thing in US/New York prisons for inmates/felons?

Yes. Per the linked article:

In 2001, Human Rights Watch estimated that at least 4.3 million inmates had been raped while incarcerated in the United States.


Why wasn't he as worried about his health

Being raped is bad for your health, both physically and psychologically.

or actually surviving those 7 years of incarceration?

Some would consider being raped to be a fate worse than death. Being shanked to death in the prison showers would be over in minutes; being raped in the prison showers would leave Monty traumatised for life.

Regarding health, rape can often include other violence.
